# Replacing sheetrock with greenboard after remodel

Tags: moisture, tiling

I'm remodeling a kitchen which will have tile extended to the ceiling behind the counters.  Currently there is relatively new sheetrock installed where the counters will go.  However there is insufficient electrical, plumbing, and mounting surfaces for open shelving.  I'm debating removing some sheetrock to make my life easier.  Since the entire wall will be covered with tile, hiding the patch shouln't be an issue.

Here is my question.  I'm debating removing 5 vertical feet and replacing it with 3x5 green board.  To be completely clear, I do not care if you think this is a waste of money.  Here is what I do want to know:

- I want to know if there is a really good reason, besides money, why I shouldn't do this.
- Is it sufficient to cover the joints behind the cabinet with mortar or would I want to skim coat the entire thing?
- when bridging the gap between sheetrock and greenboard, should I use mortar or joint compound?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need greenboard at all since this a kitchen and not a bathroom. The drywall is sufficient in a kitchen with tile. A kitchen doesn't generally have water soaking through the grout or other area that would affect the drywall. Now if having greenboard makes you feel better that there is better protection against moisture than just drywall then you should do it.

Comment: Greenboard offers little or no benefit in bathrooms anyway. If there's water soaking through the tile grout, greenboard isn't the solution.

Comment: While I see your point I don’t entirely agree. That’s like saying that galvanized steel is no better than steel since it can corrode over time. Very small amounts of moisture will destroy sheet rock. Much more exposure is required to damage green board.  I would agree though that. Getting to the root cause is always the best course.

Comment: Micah,  that’s great news if you are correct, but I’m a little concerned about near the sink. This will be the third kitchen I’ve remodeled, and in the first two the Sheetrock behind the counter near the sink was in horrible shape. I had to patch multiple places before tiling.

Comment: @mreff555 If you want to make sure that the area behind the sink is safe from water damage then do not use drywall at all there, use denshield or some other water proof barrier like in a shower.  I used denshield on the last kitchen sink wall that i found rotten studs in. ( I had to rebuild a 8 foot section of an exterior wall.)